# Can't get Django Rest Framework GET vs POST structure to differ

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Pet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    primary_contact = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

My Serializer looks like this:

```
class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'primary_contact')
```

My Viewset:

```
class PetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Pet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PetSerializer
```

My Problem:

If I do a "GET" at my endpoint, my result looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ripley",
    "description": "Black / Tan Yorkie",
    "primary_contact": 1
  }
]
```

The primary_contact only brings back the ID of the Person object. This is exactly how I want the POSTing structure to look like. When I POST, I only want to supply the ID of the Person object. However, when I GET, I want the content to look like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ripley",
    "description": "Black / Tan Yorkie",
    "primary_contact": {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "MyFistName",
        "last_name": "MyLastName",
        "phone": "312-xxx-xxxx",
        "email": "aarsan@abc123.com"
    }
  }
]
```

I can get the above structure by setting depth=2 in my serializer but then if I try to POST, it tries to create the primary_contact, which I not want to do since it already exists.

The workaround I've been using is creating a different endpoint for POST and GET when I have a foreign key, which I hope isn't the only way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You want a [nested serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships). In this case you have to `define a serializer for primary contact` and `link in with primary contact field of PetSerializer`.

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('id', 'field2', 'field3', '...')

class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    primary_contact = ContactSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'primary_contact')
```

Comment: Thanks, @cutteeth but that doesn't seem to work. It still tried to create the nested field and when I set read_only=True, If I try to POST with primary_contact: 1, it throws an error: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'primary_contact_id', table 'condoapp.dbo.condoapp_pet'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails".

Comment: Django rest Framework is having a good HTML interface. Check what a get request returns for the same post request that threw error, and try making post requests in the same format.

Comment: thanks. That is exactly how I am doing my test and how I found out it does not work.

Comment: Also, as I mentioned in my original question, I don't want to POST the same data as I am "GET"ing. I want the GET to have details about the primary_contact and I want the POST to only have the primary_contact ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can have several serializers in the same ViewSet, to achieve this you need to overwrite `get_serializer_class`method.

Take a look at this: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself